# Installing Windows on Ubuntu only by iso file without burn disc or USB

Tags: system-installation

I have only ubuntu in my computer in 100 gb system part and i have a second part 650 gb and it is empty. Before when I was using windows 7, I was installing windows 8.1 to that empty space only by opening iso file and click setup in source folder. Is it possible to do it on ubuntu if I install an application for running .exe files or .iso files?
For example if I install first a virtual windows by using vırtualbox, can I install the real windows system to my empty space by using my virtual windows. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount an ISO file in Ubuntu by using this command in terminal:

`sudo mount -o loop /location/of/iso/image.iso /media/iso`

You can then access the files in the ISO like as if they were files in your filesystem.

In order to run `.exe` files, you need to install wine with:

`sudo apt-get install wine`

Wine will execute Windows executables within Ubuntu.  But I wouldn't try installing an operating system if that's your intention.

To execute `.exe` files, you can run `wine filename.exe` in terminal, or right-click in a file manager and select "Open with Wine", or "Execute with Wine" from the menu.